# Is there a way to take the values from one column in a dataframe and append them to different dataframe's column in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm working with 2 dataframes A & B of different shapes

Dataframe A has 193 rows and 33 columns
Dataframe B has 2 rows and 196 columns

I want to be able to take a column from Dataframe A "Province or State" and have its values append on to Dataframe B's column "State".

I've tried the following

Method 1 I attempted:

```
dataframeB["State"] = dataframeA["Province or State"]
```

This doesn't fill DataframeB with 193 rows of values from Dataframe A. it justs gives

```
State
NaN
NaN
```

I want the state column to be filled with the string values from the "Province or State", how can I make this happen?

EDIT:

I was able to accomplish this by setting the row count of DataFrameB to 193 using the following method:

```
num_rows = 93
for x in np.arange(0, num_rows):
    dataframeB.loc[x] = [np.NaN for n in range(96)]
```

Then, I set dataframeB's State column to equal DataframeA's Province or state column

```
dataframeB['State'] = dataframeA['Province or State'].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Hi! This has partially worked, but it only fills up dataframeB with 2 rows of dataframeA. Is there a way to get all 193 rows of A into B?

Comment: you mean `dfB.assign(**dfA)` ??

Comment: When you say "Append",  what is that you want to do exactly? how the two dataframes connected? If you just append, with  dataframeB["State"] = dataframeA["Province or State"].values, you would get a dataframe with 196 rows and many NAN columns because your original dataframeB has only two rows!

Comment: Using the .values method gives me the following error:::: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index :-(

Comment: Hi @Laleh . I want DataframeB's State column to have the same exact data as dataframe A's 'Province or State" Column. I want to end up with Dataframe B Having 193 rows of the same data as Dataframe A's 'Province or State'.

Comment: @samumich please add samples of the 2 dataframe and an expected output, else it is hard to tell, answers will be based on guesses which will be fruitful to none.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to accomplish this by setting the row count of DataFrameB to 193 using the following method:

```
num_rows = 93
for x in np.arange(0, num_rows):
    dataframeB.loc[x] = [np.NaN for n in range(96)]
```

Then, I set dataframeB's State column to equal DataframeA's Province or state column

```
dataframeB['State'] = dataframeA['Province or State'].reset_index(drop = True)
```